# Attempting to install HP LaserJet on macOS, no DMG

Tags: hardware, scanning

I want to install an HP LaserJet Pro M1536 Multifunction Printer on macOS 10.15 Catalina. The printer already works with AirPrint. I'm attempting to setup the scanner.

I can not find .dmg, only HP Easy Start.app, e.g. Apple Store. HP Smart...

Where could I find simple dmg file?

Note this site:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201465 where it did show previously scanning not supported.

Additional question, if no dmg, downloading HP Smart, will scanner work?

Comment: I would have questioned the OP's intent rather than assume "11.1" means El Capitan, rather than Big Sur.

Comment: @Tetsujin yep, my bad

Comment: idk that particular model & mine uses the older 'HP Utility', but why not use the Easy Start?

Comment: As old as that printer is I seriously doubt you'll find any HP Scan software that will work with that model under **macOS Catalina**; however you might be able to get the **macOS** built-in app **Image Capture** to detect the device and scan from it. I had to do that on an older HP Scanner, but that was in **macOS High Sierra**.

Comment: @Tetsujin If I knew it would work 100% I would go thru hassle of AppleId and giving my cell phone # to Apple.

Comment: I'm not sure at all what your AppleID or phone number has to do with it. https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-pro-m1536-multifunction-printer-series/3974271/model/3974278 *"HP Easy Start is the new way to set up your HP printer and prepare your Mac for printing. HP Easy Start will locate and install the latest software for your printer and then guide you through printer setup."* You have yet to make it clear why you consider that only a .dmg file would be acceptable.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yep, it guided me to download app from Apple store https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hp-smart-for-desktop/id1474276998?mt=12

Comment: I've no clue what button you're pressing then. It just downloads Easy Start when I click it. Anyway, what's wrong with completing your AppleID properly, like everyone else does? I've had mine 20 years & I don't think the *[insert government department of choice]* have hacked me yet.

Comment: The link for Install HP Easy Start at https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-pro-m1536-multifunction-printer-series/3974271/model/3974278 is to a zip archive https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software12/HP_Quick_Start/osx/Applications/HP_Easy_Start.app.zip and when clicking it, it downloaded the HP_Easy_Start.app.zip file to my Downloads folder. Which of course one would double-click it to extract the HP Easy Start.app and open it to download software for the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP does NOT have a method to install drivers, a simple dmg file. One MUST use app from Apple store; hence must have an AppleId.